# Open the Url in App with Flutter on start and not with press a button

Tags: ios, iphone, flutter, dart

I want that my app open the url at the start application.
So without function ontap, onpress.
At the moment the APP working with a function on Tap

How can I do this?

Comment: onTap: () async {
              final url = 'https:www.google.it';
              if(await canLaunch(url))
              {
              launch(url);
            }
            },
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}

Answer (score 0):

just call your function or open url within initState()
initState called at the start of your app and everything you call in this will be called at the start your your app i.e. for example you want to show data from api then you have to call that function into which you are calling api's

Answer (score 0):

You should have something like this inside your `void intiState()`

```
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    if (Platform.isAndroid) {
      launchUrlString(
          'https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.livescore.cyprus');
    } else if (Platform.isIOS) {
      launchUrlString(
          'https://apps.apple.com/cy/app/futbol-cyprus-livescore/id6449159778?platform=iphone');
    }
  }
```